# Transforming simple data object into array of array of objects depending on condition

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion, data-manipulation

I have a comment/reply object, I have been trying to create a new object in the format of array of array of objects, but it's above my skill level, I am just a student currently

This is the object that I want to transform:

```
[
    {"id":9,"comment":"This is a normal comment to the post SON","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":22,"comment":"new made comment","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":23,"comment":"just let me ","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":24,"comment":"bla bla","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":29,"comment":"another comment","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":30,"comment":"reply 12 btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":29,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":31,"comment":"reply  btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":9,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
    {"id":32,"comment":"reply to reply btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":31,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null}
]
```

This is the format that I want it to end up as:

```
[
    [
        {"id":9,"comment":"This is a normal comment to the post SON","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
        {"id":31,"comment":"reply  btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":9,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
        {"id":32,"comment":"reply to reply btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":31,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null}
    ],
    [
        {"id":22,"comment":"new made comment","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null}
    ],
    [
        {"id":23,"comment":"just let me ","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null}
    ]
]
```

In other words, I want the main comment and all the replies of it(and the replies of those replies etc) to be put inside of an array, which is in an array

A few notes about the data, the `"isWhat"` can either be `"comment"` or `"reply"`, if it's a comment, it means that it's just a normal comment to the post and not a reply, and the `parentID` of it is the `ID` of the post(you shouldn't worry about that), the `parentID` of the `"isWhat: reply"` is the `parentID` of the comment it's replying to

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NicoHaase I thought of possibly looping over them all, storing the ID of the first comment, finding the parentID of that ID, I assume I the reduce method is the one I need, I watched some videos on it, but was unable to accomplish what I needed.

Comment: Don't overengineer :) If reduce sounds too complicated, find your own way to solve it. I assume there is no need for a industry-grade solution - solving it on your own and find **your** solution is of high value for your learing process

Comment: @NicoHaase I have spent 2 days trying this with different solutions, this is why I asked this here, I actually need help hah

Comment: Then have a look at the answer given by Máté. Does that help? The algorithm does not look that complicated

Comment: @NicoHaase It does not work for replies to replies, his code pushes the replies to comments but not replies to replies(etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object with all main comments (not replies)

```
{
  "9": [{"id": 9,...}],
  "22": [{"id": 22,...}],...
```

Then take all the replies, if it's a reply to comment 9 then add that comment to the object and add the reply id as key to the object referencing object["9"]:

```
{
  "9": [{"id": 9,...},"id":31,..reply to 9}],
  "22": [{"id": 22,...}],
  "31": (reference to "9")
```

If parentID cannot be found then that means the comment is too deeply nested and it's parent has not been processed yet, add the comment to items that need to be processed and go to the next item.

Keep repeating until no items are left that need to be processed.

Code can look something like this:

```js
const comments = [
  {"id":32,"comment":"reply to reply btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":31,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":9,"comment":"This is a normal comment to the post SON","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":22,"comment":"new made comment","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":23,"comment":"just let me ","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":24,"comment":"bla bla","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":29,"comment":"another comment","commentername":"noforget","parentID":42,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"comment","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":30,"comment":"reply 12 btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":29,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null},
  {"id":31,"comment":"reply  btw","commentername":"noforget","parentID":9,"commentVotes":0,"isWhat":"reply","voteToID":null,"votername":null,"voteAmount":null}
];

const groupComments = comments => {
  const recur = (o,comments)=>{
    if(comments.length===0){
      return o;
    }
    const [newO,commentsLeft] = comments.reduce(
      ([o,notProcessed],comment)=>{
        if(o[comment.parentID]){//this comment is a reply to a processed comment
          o[comment.parentID].push(comment);//add this comment to array of the thread
          //add this comment id as someone may replied to it so that other comment
          //  has parentID of this comment id. the thread of this comment is the same
          //  as the thread of it's parent or parents parents parent
          o[comment.id]=o[comment.parentID];
          return [o,notProcessed];
        }
        //current comment has a parentID that is not processed yet, this could be
        //  because it's nested several levels, add comment to notProcessed
        return [o,notProcessed.concat(comment)];
      },
      [o,[]]
    );
    return recur(newO,commentsLeft);
  }
  const grouped = recur(
    comments.reduce(
      (o,comment)=>{//create an object where keys are the id's of comments that are not replies
        if(!(comment.isWhat==="comment")){
          return o;
        }
        o[comment.id]=o[comment.id] || [];
        o[comment.id].push(comment);
        return o;
      },
      {}
    ),
    comments.filter(c=>c.isWhat!=="comment")//only the replies
  );
  return comments.filter(c=>c.isWhat==="comment")//each comment that is not a reply
  .map(x=>x.id)//take the id of comment that is not a reply
  .reduce(
    (all,key)=>all.concat([grouped[key]]),//add to the array the o[mainComment.id]
    []
  );
}

console.log(
  groupComments(comments)
  //this part is to map to only id and parentid for simpler output
  .map(
    comments=>comments.map(
      ({id,parentID})=>({id,parentID})
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need recursion here; if comments are ordered so that parents always come before children (which is pretty safe to assume), this can be done in a single pass.

Assuming `comments` is the name of your input array:

```
var result = [];
var threadsById = {};

for (let comment of comments) {
    if (comment.isWhat == 'comment') {
        var thread = [];
        result.push(thread);
        threadsById[comment.id] = thread;
    }
    else {
        threadsById[comment.parentID].push(comment);
    }
}
```